# How to activate a range in excel VBA using ActiveCell.Offset

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to activate the range 4 across and 'n' down from the current active cell. I am new to VBA and programming as a whole.

I have tried putting each "ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)" in its own parentheses and without. It also works with the first as "ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)" but I want the upper left cell in the activated range to be the original ActiveCell

```vb
     Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(n, 4)).Activate
```

When I put ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) in their own parentheses I get an error message "method 'range' of object '_global' failed". Ran without the parentheses it just does nothing at all without an error.

Comment: I think you want `.Select` on the end instead.  And remove `.Offset(0,0)`

Comment: or just use `Resize`: `ActiveCell.Resize(n,4).select`

Comment: as mentioned by  @chris neilsen in his answer try to avoid using select/activate entirely. What is it you want to do with the range? Most likely there's a way to do it without selection or activating it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.activate)

> Range.Activate method
>
> Activates a single cell, which must be inside the current selection. To select a range of cells, use the [Select method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.select)

So, your code could be

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(n, 4)).Select
```

That said, consider not using Activate/Select at all.  [See here for how](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/445425).